# Copy contents to Clipboard

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a need where in my application, I need to copy the URL that is rendered to the user. I am using the JS from this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGEf7/).

My code is slightly different from the HTML part of the Fiddle. I use [mscConfirm](https://github.com/brijeshb42/medium-style-confirm) for the JS message box.

My show.js.erb file,

```
 <% if @exists == true %>
        mscConfirm("Hold on", 'The file has been shared already, <%= @display %>', function(){
            clipboard(this);
        });
<% end %>
```

The function in the above code, is executed on clicking OK to the Message that appears. On doing Ctrl + C to the @display value in the screen, I still get 'undefined' when I try to paste it elsewhere.

My textfield output after pasting,

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its displaying correctly on my end. Where are you trying to paste the copied text?

Comment: In a textfield. Updated my question with the output screen for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided `clipboard()` function accepts a DOM element. You will have to modify the function to suit your requirements.

```
function clipboard(el, txt) {
  // deselect all
  var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      selected[i].className = '';
  };
  el.className = 'selected';
  clip.setValue(txt);
}
```

Here, you will have to explicitly pass the text to be copied. In `mscConfirm`'s okCallback, `this` does not refer to any element.

So according to me, your function call should look like this:

```
<% if @exists == true %>
    mscConfirm("Hold on", 'The file has been shared already, <%= @display %>', function(){
        clipboard(document.getElementById("DOMnodeID"), @display);
    });
<% end %>
```

Or you can remove the DOMnode altogether and just pass the text to be copied:

```
function clipboard(txt) {
  // deselect all
  var selected = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
  for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      selected[i].className = '';
  };
  clip.setValue(txt);
}
```

Then your function call should look like this:

```
<% if @exists == true %>
    mscConfirm("Hold on", 'The file has been shared already, <%= @display %>', function(){
        clipboard(@display);
    });
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks Brijesh, I am now able to pass the @display value to the clipboard function. Thanks much. :)